# iOS7, backwards compatibility and launch images

Tags: ios, image, app-store, uitabbar, splash-screen

I want to submit an iOS app that is prepared to run in iOS5+ versions. It is a tabbed app, so the launch images I got for iOS6 and earlier have the default shine in the tab bar's background. However, now that I compiled the app also for iOS7, the tab bar's background has no shine. I keep the default tab bar's appearance for each iOS version, I mean, when my app is running in an iOS6- device it has the shine effect, and it has no shine when running in iOS7 (I've seen than some apps have adopted the new appearance even for iOS versions prior to 7, like Twitter app).

Since Apple's Human Interface Guidelines says that the launch image should look like your app's main view (without controls)... which launch images should I provide? iOS7-like, or iOS6-like?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set different launch screens for iOS 6 and iOS 7. Take a look at this picture from Xcode 5 (Project properties page, under "Launch Images"): [image: Screenshot of launch screen selection in Xcode 5]

Anyway, it's not an enforcement from Apple, ie., if your launch screen doesn't match the main app screen exactly, your app will not be rejected.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I find hard to know what things in Human Interface Guidelines are a requirement or what are more like a recommendation...

Answer (score 0):

Xcode lets you specify launch images for iOS 6 and below and iOS 7 plus. So you can keep your old images, and just make new ones for iOS 7.

Comment: Ok, thanks! In a similar way... will it be possible to provide different screenshots for each iOS version in iTunes Connect?

Comment: @AppsDev: Probably. I can't tell you for sure, but that would make sense.